# How to get type of group by query?

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I try to get list of query results and  return for method value but get error.

> The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How can I do this?

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetCountSubjectCategories()
{
    try
    {
        IEnumerable<T> countSubjectsList = (from blog in db.BlogTables
                                            group blog by blog.CatId
                                            into catgy
                                            select new
                                            {
                                                Id = catgy.Key,
                                                CountSubjects = catgy.Count()                                   }).ToList();
        return countSubjectsList;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.AddErrorLog(e, AdakLog.Service.DataBase, "1", false, false, true);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare a class

```
public class CategorySubjects
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Subjects { get; set; }
}
```

and then return an `IEnumerable<CategorySubjects>`.

```
public IEnumerable<CategorySubjects> GetCountSubjectCategories()
{
    try
    {
        return (from blog in db.BlogTables
                group blog by blog.CatId
                into catgy
                select new CategorySubjects
                {
                    Id = catgy.Key,
                    CountSubjects = catgy.Count()
                };
            return countSubjectsList;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.AddErrorLog(e, AdakLog.Service.DataBase, "1", false, false, true);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Another option it would to create `Tuple<int,int>` with two properties or a `struct`. The use of `T` in your code didn't make sence. Usually, we use `T` when we have to define a generic method or a class that would expose some generic behaviour. If you want to start reading about generics, you could start [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx).